# Jquery to grey-out parts of the web page

Tags: php, jquery, layout, css

I have a design as show in the below image and i have a requirement where user can click on the link in Rectangular area named as A, B & C. When one click on the click here link in Box B then all the green area should gray out except the **BOX B** and same should happen with  BOX A, C.

Example as shown in image.
***When User open the page***
[image: One User open the page]

When User Click on the BOX B link
[image: When User Click on the BOX B link]

I am not sure if this is possible if there is any similar example where i can start from. I looked for but could not find similar example. Usually they example are related to whole page grey-out.

I can do same by using onmouseover and replace the whole image with the another image which has surrounding area in grey. But i am not allowed to do it this way. I am not sure if this is possible. I would appreciate if you can point me in right direction or if this is possible to certain area of page in grey..

These page are designed for PHP scripting

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Srj82/ (see answer below)

Comment: I appreciate everyone help who contributed their time for solution to this problem. I had couple of good option By "jAndy" Gave me a working example which i can implement in web page. I am still learning jQuery and it is a waste ocean ... Thanks jAndy. Stack Overflow comes to rescue to people like me who have no one around to guide when they hit any problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a little example for you, which you can find here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Srj82/

Its' basically using a simple css `z-index` to overlap / hide the entire place, while the current selected element got temporarily a higher `z-index` than the overlapping `<div>`.

You'll notice, while the overlapping `<div>` is visible, you can still click on the selected box. Anything else is not reachable (without removing event handlers or so). Just because there is another element which overlaps the rest.

Comment: @jAndy- Thanks for great solution. Can you also show me how i can only grey out the box which a user click and so on.. I need your direction..

Comment: I can do it with this code also $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#DivID").fadeTo("slow",0.25);
  });
});

Comment: Kudos for the jsfiddle example.   Note however that if the <div> that you intend to leave visible doesn't have it's own explicit background set, it will appear to have it's background grayed out as well.

Answer (score 0):

On click of A/B/C you can add a div overlay with a transparent grey bg color and increase the z-index of the clicked element higher than the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to temporarily change positioning of the element to `absolute` and give it a high `z-index`, then add a layer below it that would act as the overlay.

You could also use a plugin, for example this one: http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/toolbox/expose.html

Answer (score 0):

Use an overlay div that will be positioned absolutely above anything else on your page with z-index then set your clicked box's z-index to overlay's + 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but a relatively quick and easy way is to make the elements that you need to grey out be of the same class. Then when you select an item give that element an additional class, and change the css for the elements named above except for the selected element with the additional class.

[This is a link describing one way to accomplish this.](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to place an `div` over the area where A,B,C are placed.
In this div you will have a `background-color` like so :

```
#myDivHider{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    display:none;
}
```

When you either click a,b or c You "activate" (`display:block`), the whole thing and set the z.index of your a,b or C that it get's up "higher".

An alternative would be a plugin from jQueryTools, called Expose.

- http://jquerytools.org/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html